# Animate two objects, at the same timeline. One after another. WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I animate the opacity of two objects, at the same timeline, but in different intervals?

I was expecting the two text elements, to fade in gradually, from one textbox to another. Instead, The text appears out of sync and, it flashes in and out.

```
    <Window x:Class="Hello_world.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hello_world"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Hello world with WPF" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        

        <TextBlock Name="primary_adverb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello world." VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Source Code Pro Black" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red">
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="primary_adverb"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"                 
                                From="0" To="2" Duration="0:0:10" BeginTime="0:0:1"
                            />

                            

                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
        
        <TextBlock Name="Noir_N" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="N" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Source Code Pro Black" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="WhiteSmoke">
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Noir_N"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"                 
                                From="2" To="3" Duration="0:0:10" BeginTime="0:0:5"
                            />
                        </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>           
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="Noir_O" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="O" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Source Code Pro Black" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Width="43"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Noir_I" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="455,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="I" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Source Code Pro Black" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Width="42"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Noir_R" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="616,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="R" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Source Code Pro Black" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Width="42"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Where is the sense in animating an Opacity from 2 to 3? The effective interval is [0..1]

Comment: The problem is that the character "N", shows up on screen, instead of hiding and then, after a second it disappears and it fades into existence.

Comment: To repeat what Clemens said: Other than "0", the Opacity values you're using are "invalid".

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

#### 1. Set initial `<TextBlock>` Opacity to 0

If you want an item to fade in, you need to set the `<TextBlock>` tag's `Opacity="0"`. The sets the initial opacity value at 0 to start. In your case, you wait 1 second prior to fading in, so that is the reason it flickers. The original value is the default of `1`, then animation sets it to `0` and then fades back to `1` (which is the max).

#### 2. Opacity goes from 0 to 1

In your code, the 'N' `<DoubleAnimation>` tag fades from the `<TextBlock>`'s opacity from `2` to `3`, which is effectively setting it from `1` to `1`, in essence not fading at all. Opacity is a percentage, so the only values that are valid are those between `0` and `1` representing 0% to 100% opaque/visible.

#### 3. Use `<DoubleAnimation>`'s `BeginTime` property to offset starts

If you want it to start fading in immediately, you should set `<DoubleAnimation>` tag's `BeginTime="0:0:0"`. In the example below, I think I have everything working the way you want. I did speed up the animation, though, just because I thought it looked a little smoother.

```xml
<!-- Add Opacity="0" -->
<TextBlock Name="primary_adverb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello world." VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Source Code Pro Black" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"
    Opacity="0" >
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- Change to 0 to 1 and BeginTime 0:0:0 -->
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="primary_adverb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:05" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>

<!-- Add Opacity="0" -->
<TextBlock Name="Noir_N" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="N" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Source Code Pro Black" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
    Opacity="0" >
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- Change to 0 to 1 and BeginTime 0:0:05 -->
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Noir_N" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:05" BeginTime="0:0:02" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Result
[image]

This also works if you keep going and extend the same logic to the rest of the letters, adding `Opacity="0"` to your `<TextBlock>` tags and incrementing the `BeginTime="0:0:02"` of the `<DoubleAnimation>` tag. You can see my full solution here which generates the following:
https://github.com/EvanGeer/StackOverflowAnswers/blob/master/StackOverflowAnswers.Revit/StackOverflowAnswers.App/AnimateTwoItems.xaml
[image]

Comment: If you look at the BeginTime parameter of both objects, it only works with the first object, which says "Hello World.". The second object, which is "N" appears from the beginning of the animation, in full opacity and then, it turns dark and animates itself into existence, after the set time is passed. So that is the problem.

Comment: @George, you need to set the opacity of that textblock to 0. I will update my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: The problem is simply not with the parameter for opacity, because it works fine for the clause "Hello World", without setting its opacity to zero. Something else is going on, which we cannot see.

Comment: Are the screenshots I posted not what you are looking for?

Comment: If BeginTime is 0, then You're right that you don't need it. But you if there is a delay as the default value is 1.